# SEO permalinks not constantly showing up properly on google

Tags: seo, google-search, yoast

When searching my site on Google. I have some correct and some wrong when it comes down to the meta permalink. I have a photo that explains itself. Wondering why this is happening to some but not for others? Possibly saving it differently in the past? not sure. The actual permalink is correct on the main URL, but on google some are wrong.

This example below shows one right and the one below is wrong.. should have /dental-implants > all-on-4

[image]

Currently, I am using WordPress and Yoast, I have LightSpeed Caching.. Is there a setting I need to have enabled for the caching part? Just wondering what is going wrong?

Thanks!

Update!!
[image]

Comment: Why would you say the first one is "correct" when the second one looks better.   The first one is cut off with an ellipsis.  The information in it appears to just replicate the information in the title.   The second one looks a lot better to me.

Comment: the permalink should be dental implants > All-On-4

Comment: Or just All-On-4.. However they all seem to have Dental Implants as the breadcrumb

Comment: Are you sure you don't have nested category tags?

Comment: I'm not sure.. I remember at one point installing a plugin that adds categories to pages. Could that be a possible issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your breadcrumb markup is indeed valid, but it has an additional nesting level, in comparison with the markup, which makes Google as an example.

Look, your markup for the last piece, All-On-4, looks like:

```
{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 3,
    "item": {
        "@type": "WebPage",
        "@id": "https://772implant.com/dental-implants/all-on-4/",
        "url": "https://772implant.com/dental-implants/all-on-4/",
        "name": "Dental Implants > All-On-4"
    }
}
```

You markup `item` an extra type. But look, [how Google does it](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb?hl=en#json-ld):

```
{
        "@type": "ListItem",
        "position": 2,
        "name": "Science Fiction",
        "item": "https://example.com/books/sciencefiction"
      }
```

You see: `item` is just an `URL`, without aditional nesting level.

I realized in many cases: nesting often makes Google not (fully) understand structured data. Earlier i thought it would be the best practice to make single JSON-LD snippet for the whole web document. Earning more experience with the subject i begun to create extra snippets for every important data type - own snippet for breadcrumb, own snippet for aggregatedRating and so on.

I don't say, you should do the same (own snippet for every data type) - but i'm pretty sure: avoiding nesting, specially on places like here, where you can go without, helps Google better understand your markup.

Comment: Thank you for getting back! That is understandable. I removed all the Yoast breadcrumb titles.  Although, this problem was happening before I added breadcrumb titles, maybe it will fix the issue. Did you use Search Console to find my markup? Did my changes wind up working?

Comment: :) i can't use search console until you invite me and share your property access with me. But no need for this. Don't 100% understand, what do you mean with `wind up working`, but if you fixed everything, so wait some time and check SERP again.

Comment: It means does my page have the correct markup now? I'm not sure if I made the proper fix, and would like to see if I did. Thanks!

Comment: There is a weird thing happening where the slug/name of the parent page is "Dental Implants" for all the listings with that parent URL associated with it.. Same with my /dentures. I'll add a screenshot